# Can I use attr_accessible on non database backed fields in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following Michael Hartls rails tutorial . Here is the User model class .

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :nick_name
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_secure_password
end
```

The User table in database doesnt contain password/password_confirmation fields. It only has a

```
password_digest
```

field.  I'm confused , Shouldn't I be using an attr_accessor method on fields that are not present in a table ? I thought that the code must look something like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :nick_name
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_secure_password
end
```

Because password/password_confirmation are not present in table column , Is'nt attr_accessor  required ? I'm thoroughly confused .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/826a85069627060c11baf932423702b1228dd4df/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L34) and it will make sense why the `User` class does not call `attr_accessor :password`. The macro itself calls `attr_reader :password` and you have no need for a `password_confirmation` accessor.

You also need to think of what the `User` class should actually be concerned with. `password` and `password_confirmation` has to do with authentication. Even though `has_secure_password` ends up defining authentication related methods in the `User` class, I argue that we should not be concerned with the implementation details of authentication specifically in the `User` class. Instead [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password_rb.html) is. Hence you should not be concerned with defining methods for `password` and `password_confirmation` unless specific features that you yourself are defining need to access these attributes.

It's just unfortunate that `attr_accessible` is required to allow mass assignment of these values in the controller. But there's a reason why this is [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5d85709d346e55827e88f53430a2cbe1e5fb9e/activemodel/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb#L13) in Rails 4.

Comment: Ah..Thanks a lot . I always forget to read the source . Can I ask why it is bad that attr_accessible is required for password and password_confirmation ?

Comment: Can you also tell me ,where are we defining the variables password,password_confirmation, name etc ? In the above code , Are they like class instance variables ?

Comment: It's not necessarily "bad", but going by my argument in the answer, specifying the "accessibility" of these two attributes give knowledge of implementation details to the `User` class about authentication. My argument is that `User` should not really care about the implementation details of authentication since we're relying on `has_secure_password` to do that for us. I personally trust the developers who wrote this macro and therefore I as the writer of `User` don't need to worry about white-listing attributes that are `has_secure_password` specific.

Comment: `password` is an instance variable managed by `has_secure_password` as shown in the source. `password_confirmation` is not an instance variable, nor class instance variable, They are accepted as arguments to `new`, `create` and etc. in order to confirm that the submitted password is really intended when the object is created.

Answer (score 1):

No need to be confused. You are right, `attr_accessor` is required for non-db backed fields, as it's the getter/setter for that field. On the other hand, `attr_accessible` is used by Rails to identify which properties are allowed to be assigned by a request (aka. a white list). Given your example, if you don't include `password` and `password_confirmation` in the `attr_accessible` attributes, you wouldn't be able to mass assign them in a request.

Comment: So, If I add attr_accessor on password, what is the additional functionality that I can get ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, and the password field is not backed by the database, then you gain the ability to get and set its contents. Then if you add it to attr_accessible, you can mass assign.